# How can I use my own domain with vapor cloud

Tags: vapor, vapor-cloud

How can I use my own domain when hosting on vapor cloud?

I have never written an API before and just started playing around with Vapor, I purchased a domain from godaddy and would like my API to use that for my routes instead of the domain Vapor is creating ex "appname.vapor.cloud"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the docs for adding your custom domain to Vapor Cloud - https://docs.vapor.cloud/custom-domain/add-domain/